# Launcher for Skype with webcam

Tags: 14.04, bash, launcher, skype, webcam

I am a newbie on Linux distributions... I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, and I would like to create a launcher for skype with this particular command:

```
bash -c 'LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 skype'
```

It makes my webcam run smoothly in skype, thing is that I don't want to open a terminal and copy/paste this command each time I want to login, so I tried to create a document like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Exec=bash -c 'LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 skype'
Name=SkypeWC
Icon=blank
```

renamed it as `skype.desktop`, but all I get is this message each time I try to lauch the app:

```
"There was an error launching the application"
```

What am I doing wrong folks?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exec line should look like this:

```
Exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype %U
```